# Best way to find similar items in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have 1M numbers:N[], and 1 single number n, now I want to find in those 1M numbers that are similar to that single number, say an area of [n-10, n+10]. 
what's the best way in python to do this? Do I have to sort the 1M number and do an iteration?

Comment: not exactly the same, but in the area of [n-10, n+10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[x for x in N if n - 10 <= x <= n + 10]`

Comment: will this do an whole 1M number iteration?

Comment: Yes, it's still a loop behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

```
results=[x for x in numbers if x >= n-10 and x <= n+10]
```

Comment: `results=[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if x >= n-10 and x <= n+10]` if you want to keep track of the indices of the similar numbers.

Comment: Python supports chained comparison operators like `n - 10 <= x <= n + 10`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
is_close_to_n = lambda x: n-10 <= x <= n+10
result = filter(is_close_to_n, N)
```

Generalizing a bit:

```
def is_close_to(n):
    f = lambda x: n-10 <= x <= n+10
    return f

result12 = filter(is_close_to(12), N)
result123 = filter(is_close_to(123), N)
```

Do *not* sort. Sorting is, in general, O(n log n); brute-force searching is O(n).

Comment: Thanks, What if I have those numbers sorted? Is there a O(log n) and simple solution for this? like do a binary search? Do python have some thing like "self defined compare function"?

Comment: If the list is already sorted, you can use binary search to find the index i1 of the first element >=n-10. Then proceed forward (in a while loop) to find the index i2 of the first element >n+10. N[i1:i2] should then be what you're loking for. What do you mean by "self defined compare function"?

Comment: I mean if have a library function like this

binary_search(N,n,cmp=mycompare)

def mycompare(x,n):
    if n-10<x<n+10:
        return true
    else
        return false

Comment: bisect module might also also help, if they're sorted.